# Can i get all the data from google distance matrix api in one HTTP request?

Tags: android, google-distancematrix-api

I am using google distance matrix api to get the driving time between 2 coordinates.

**This is my method for getting the data:**

```
 private void testDistanceApi(String url) throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println("this is my response --------" +response);
}
```

**And this is the response that i am getting:**

```
 System.out: this is my response --------Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=32.002700,%2034.750875&destinations=31.963263,%2034.748292&key=AIzaSyAzFFPgX-GryNpheDClG-PpEr1OGuHm6OY}
```

In the `response` (JSON) there is the URL (as you can see in the print), I want to know If I can get the JSON from the URL without using another HTTP request.

The URL from the JSON:

```
url=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=32.002700,%2034.750875&destinations=31.963263,%2034.748292&key=AIzaSyAzFFPgX-GryNpheDClG-PpEr1OGuHm6OY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I never parsed the response into JSON, there is no need for another HTTP request. I just parsed the response like this  :

```
    String resStr = response.body().string();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resStr);
    System.out.println("jsonnnnn????" + json);
```